# phpunit Classes are not loaded in tests

Tags: namespaces, phpunit, php-7, autoload

I try to create my own library, with it's own namespace so it can be included in other projects.

I have done that and composer install runs without errors, but when I try to run my unit tests in my library it doesn't find any classes neither for mocking or for direct initialisation.

My folder structure is like this:

```
ProjectFolder
|
\_src
|    \_Sap
|         \_Classes
|
\_tests     
|     \_Sap
|         \_TestClasses  
|     bootstrap.php
\_vendor
```

The namespace used in classes follows this pattern:

```
namespace PuC\Sap;
```

The one used in the tests has this pattern:

```
namespace PuC\Sap\Tests\Sap;
```

My composer.json looks like this:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "PuC\\Sap\\": "src/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "PuC\\Sap\\Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
```

In my tests folder I have added a bootstrap.php and refer to it in my phpunit.xml file:

```
<?php

$loader = @include __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php')
$loader->add('Sap', __DIR__);
```

No when I run this in the bash I get:

```
$ bin/phpunit tests/
PHPUnit 8.4.3 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
......

7) PuC\Sap\Tests\Sap\HouseSoapServiceTest::testGetHouseData
Cannot stub or mock class or interface "PuC\Sap\Client\SapSoapClient" which does not exist
```

Same problem when I try to initialise the class directly.

Are my paths wrong? My namespaces?

Comment: Does `src/Client/SapSoapClient.php` exist? If not, your PSR-4 autoloader rules may be incorrect

Comment: It is placed under src/Sap/Client/SapSoapClient.php
do you think the subfolder "Sap" under "src" is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the additional folder in my src folder. With this modified structure the tests are passing and the classes are found:

```
ProjectFolder
|
\_src
|    \_Classes
|
\_tests     
|     \_Sap
|         \_TestClasses  
|     bootstrap.php
\_vendor
```

Thanks to Robbie Averill for pointing me in the right direction.